# Problem with installation of semMediation package on Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu

I'm trying to install the `semMediation` package on Ubuntu through devtools:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("cardiomoon/semMediation")
```

[reference](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/200846_3a7fb7a163314ccd94c3e0a93e46b71b.html).

But:

```
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  HTTP error 404.
  Not Found

  Did you spell the repo owner (`cardiomoon`) and repo name (`semMediation`) correctly?
  - If spelling is correct, check that you have the required permissions to access the repo.
```

What can it be?

Comment: Can you please check the cardiomoon github [page](https://github.com/cardiomoon?after=Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpK5MjAxNy0xMS0xM1QxNjo0Njo1OS0wNTowMM4GMHkv&tab=repositories).  I don't see any repo with that name

Comment: @akrun See [here](https://github.com/cardiomoon/r-sem/blob/master/ADHD.Rmd).

Comment: there is an r-sem page [here](https://github.com/cardiomoon/r-sem/blob/master/ADHD.Rmd)

Comment: I am unable to install the package.

Answer (score 0):

There was a semMediation package on github. The author of the package wrote a tutorial on RPubs.[See below][1]

[1]: https://rpubs.com/cardiomoon/200846

However, I don't see any repo with semMediation right now. Maybe because the author deleted the repo. 
But you can still search a repo name with "semMediation" in All Github, because someone might fork that repo.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
devtools::install_github("guhjy/semMediation")
```

And be happy